# How to define local ng-model in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Below is a simple example using `ng-repeat`.

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names">
    <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="value" ng-change="checkName(name, value)">{{name}}</label>
</div>
```

I need one `value` as `ng-model` for each checkbox and I am passing that `value` into `checkName()` function. However, I don't need `value` in my JavaScript code or elsewhere. I don't want to use something like `name.value`.

Is there any way to define the `ng-model` only for local use? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-init`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names">
    <label><input type="checkbox" ng-init="value = true" ng-model="value" ng-change="checkName(name, value)">{{name}}</label>
</div>
```